# Nginx location blocks factcgi php inheritance issue

Tags: nginx

I have a configuration file which reads a little like the below.

I have a mediawiki installation under the subfolder /wiki/ represented by its location block. I then have a default location / which serves the main part of the site. I have an embedded .php catch in the /wiki/ location block which seems to work. However, I have a legacy requirement in the default .php block to auto_prepend a file.

When making calls to /wiki/ this file is loaded. I presume because nginx is somehow falling into that block. Can someone explain whats wrong here?

I suppose I could ignore the /wiki/ with regex in the default .php block. But fishing for some other ideas.

Many thanks

```
  server {
  listen *:80;

  server_name           www.somesite.com
  error_page 404 /404error.html;

  index  index.php;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://www.street-crime.com$request_uri;
  }

  location @extensionless-php {
    internal;


    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }

  location ^~ /wiki {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root  /var/www/html/somesite/current;
    try_files $uri $uri /wiki/index.php?query_string;

        location ~ /wiki/(.*\.php)$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 3m;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3m;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 3m;
        }
  }

  location @missing {

    root          /var/www/html/somesite/current;
    include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files     /bootstrap/routes.php =404;

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE   auto_prepend_file="/var/www/html/somesite/current/includes/boot.php";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/bootstrap/routes.php;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3m;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {

    root          /var/www/html/somesite/current;
    include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files     $uri @missing;

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE auto_prepend_file="/var/www/html/somesite/current/includes/boot.php";
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3m;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`? May be it's there?

Comment: I can confirm it's not in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

Comment: From the looks of it, it sounds like you've oversimplified your sample config presented here that you might have as well removed the issue you're reporting...